# Trouble switching between pagestyles

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am working with the following document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{13.6pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \cfoot{\thepage}
}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\pagestyle{fancy}

\include{text/intro}
\include{text/methods}
\include{text/results}
\include{text/discussion}

\end{document}
```

I want the table of contents to be formatted with my own definition of the `plain`style, but the rest of the document should be in the `fancy` style.

The problem is that the second `\pagestyle{fancy}` call doesn't seem to do anything. All the subsequent pages are formatted as `\pagestyle{plain}`. The problem seems to go away when i remove my redefinition of `plain`. I don't understand this behavior, can anyone shed some light?

Comment: What if you give another name to your version of `plain`?

Comment: @Bernard: Should do. Go on, provide an answer ;-)

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: I'll do it in a moment. I want to test first if the same problem happens with `titleps`, which I find easier to use.

Comment: @hristian Hupfer: Didn't work as suggested with `fancyhdr` :o( So I  proposed an alternative solution, based on `titleps`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose a solution with the `titleps` package, from the `titlesec` bundle. You even don't have to refine plain. I defined a `myfancy` page style, that mimics the default `fancy` pagestyle from `fancyhdr`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

 \usepackage{titleps}
 \newpagestyle{myfancy}{%
 \headrule
 \sethead[][][\itshape\MakeUppercase{\thesection\enspace\sectiontitle}]{\itshape \MakeUppercase{\thesection\enspace \sectiontitle}}{}{}
 \setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
 }

\renewpagestyle{plain}{%
\headrule
\sethead{}{}{}
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\pagestyle{myfancy}

\section{text/intro}
\newpage
\section{text/methods}
\newpage
\section{text/results}
\newpage
\section{text/discussion}


\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: While this takes care of the issue, it is no different from removing the redefinition of `plain` in my original example. I need to redefine it because I want the rule on top of the `plain` pages as well.

Comment: Not exactly, since what worked for me was only `\thispagestyle{plain]`, which is problematic if the table of contents is several pages long. Anyway, `\renewpagestyle`  works well with `titleps`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Yep, that does the trick, I will use that for now. However, if anyone can explain why my original attempt did not work I would be very grateful. I would prefer to use `fancyhdr` if I can, as I found the documentation to be much more helpful.

Comment: @lydhvin: I don't know fancyhdr details well enough to explain. What's funny is I could say the same as you about titleps vs fancyhdr… It is much more transparent to use `\sectiontitle`, `\chaptertitle` and the like than `\leftmark` and `\rightmark`. Furthermore, if necessary you can have a sophisticated use of marks.

Comment: I'll take your word for it:) I am sure titleps is a better package, but the documentation was somewhat cryptic for a casual user like myself. I find the fancyhdr documentation to be clearer. But anyway, I'll mark the question as answered for now, at least until I can find a solution using fancyhdr. Thanks!

Comment: After spending a little time with `titleps` I recant my previous statement. It is much easier to work with and I was looking at the wrong doumentation (the `titlesec` docs, which popped up when I googled `titleps` and provides very little information on `titleps`). Silly me.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know why your example does not work. But there are two suggestions with `fancyhdr`.

You can change the pagestyle locally:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{13.6pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \cfoot{\thepage}
}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}

{\pagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage}

\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Or you can define a new style for the main part:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{13.6pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \cfoot{\thepage}
}
\fancypagestyle{myfancy}{
\fancyhead[L]{\slshape\rightmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\slshape\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\pagestyle{myfancy}
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: The first workaround works beautifully, thanks. The second one is problematic. It works if I call `\pagestyle{myfancy}` before `\pagestyle{plain}` and `\tableofcontents` and then `\pagestyle{myfancy}` again. But if I omit the first `\pagestyle{myfancy}` it makes all the headers for the rest of the documents say CONTENT instead of the current section and subsection. This is getting weird.